# Error IM004 when using ODBC to access SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, mfc, odbc

I'm developing an MFC project and using ODBC to connect to a SQL Server 2008 server. Each time when I'm about to read from or write to the database, I always construct a `CXXX` (as a class derived from `CRecordset` and have bound all useful fields by RDX) object, open it, operate the database, and close it.
However, after about 1000 such operations, the ODBC driver reports error, which has a `SQLSTATE:IM004` in it, and refuse to work from then on.
From the error string, I learned that it is due to environment handle allocation error. But I don't know what it is, or why it is.
Please explain this to me and give me some advice about how to pinpoint the problem. Thank you.